# Private class in a Vector used publicly

Tags: java, vector, private, public

In Java, what happens when you reference a private class in a `Vector` from outside the class?

Example:

```
public class A {
  private class B {}
  public Vector<B> vector = new Vector<B>();

  public A() {
    vector.add(new B());
  }
}

public class C {
  public C() {
    A a = new A();
    a.vector.get(0); // <- What does this return?
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do all these Vector examples come from? Is there some learning material out there preaching Vector instead of ArrayList?

Comment: Are you asking me?  The example is something I whipped up.  I never knew that ArrayList is faster than Vector.  It doesn't say anything in  the javadocs that I can find.  I've always used Vector due to my C++/STL background.

Comment: Usually, people use ArrayList rather than Vector. There are some cases people use Vector, for thread-safe purpose, for example

Comment: Vector is pretty much an obsolete class. Unless you need the specific sorts of thread safety it provides, use ArrayList. It's so much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    Object o = a.vector.get(0); // <- What does this return?
    System.out.println(o.getClass());
}
```

The class is A$B, so it knows that B is an inner class of A.

But you cannot access any of the members of B. For example, if you change class A to this:

```
public class A {
  private class B {
      public int x;
  }
  public Vector<B> vector = new Vector<B>();

  public A() {
    vector.add(new B());
    vector.get(0).x = 10;
  }
}
```

You still won't be able to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.vector.get(0).x); // this won't compile
}
```

It will say `the type A.B is not visible`.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the reference to an Object of type A$B.

You will be able to assign it to an `Object` reference, e.g.

```
Object o = a.vector.get( 0 );
```

You can even use reflection to investigate properties of `o`.

Just a general reminder, please use `java.util.ArrayList` instead of Vector.

Answer (score 1):

It will return an object of type A.B However you cannot do anything with it really because you will not be able to assign it to a variable or call any methods on it.  If you do:

```
System.out.println(a.vector.get(0));
```

you will get something like:

```
A$B@42e816
```

Comment: If you add a toString() method it will nicely printout whatever toString() returns. However if you call toString() directly it will fail to compile.